# Tfidvectorizer - L2 normalized vector

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization, tf-idf

I want to ensure that the TfidfVectorizer object is returning a l2 normalized vector. I am running a binary classification problem with documents of varied length.

I am trying to extract the normalized vectors of each corpora, so I assumed I could just sum up each row of the Tfidfvectorizer matrix. However the sum is greater than 1, I thought a normalized copora would transform all documents to a range between 0-1.

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents='unicode',
stop_words=stopwords,analyzer='word', use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenizer, ngram_range=(1,2),sublinear_tf= True , norm='l2')

tfidf = vect.fit_transform(X_train)
# sum norm l2 documents
vect_sum = tfidf.sum(axis=1)
```

The values of vect_sum are greater than 1, I thought using norm would result in all vectors to be between 0-1. I was just made aware of a preprocessing object in scikit learn - [preprocessing.normalizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer). 
Is that something I should use in the pipeline of Gridsearch? See example below.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('plb', normalize(tfidf, norm='l2')), #<-- sklearn.preprocessing
    ('tfidf', tfidf_vectorizer),
    ('clf', MultinomialNB()),  
])
```

What is the difference between preprocessing.normalizer and Tfidfvectorizer norm parameter ?

Answer (score 5):

With L2, it is not the sum of the rows that is equal to 1, but the sum of the squares is equal to 1. The L1 norm will produce a norm where the sum of the values equals 1.

```
X_train = [" This is my first sentence", "Short sentence"]
vect = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents='unicode',analyzer='word', use_idf=True, ngram_range=(1,2),sublinear_tf= True , norm='l2')

tfidf = vect.fit_transform(X_train)
# sum norm l2 documents
vect_sum = tfidf.multiply(tfidf).sum(axis=1)
vect_sum

# matrix([[ 1.],
#         [ 1.]])
```

TF-IDF only applies to counts. You could achieve the same effect if you perform the `normalize` after TF-IDF weights are produced.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import normalize

vect = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents='unicode',analyzer='word', use_idf=True, ngram_range=(1,2),
                       sublinear_tf= True , norm=None)

tfidf = vect.fit_transform(X_train)
tfidf = normalize(tfidf)
```

This would be equivalent to the `TfidfVectorizer(..., norm='l2')` in the original example.